# Checking variable from a different class in C#

Tags: c#

Greetings-

I have 2 classes.  One is called "Programs" and the other is called "Logs".  The class called Programs has `public const string m_sEnviron = "";` near the top and I need to check what the m_sEnviron variable is set to through my class called Logs.  The variable m_sEnviron will get set from a scheduler called Tidal so how can I check its value from a different class.  If this is not the best to do this then please let me know what the better ways are.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

```
Namespace NightScripts
{
   class Program
   {

      public static string m_sEnviron {get; set;} 

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

      }

      //Lots of other functions...

   }

   class Logs
   {
      //I try to get access to m_sEnviron but it will not show after I type Program.
   }
}
```

Comment: If you declare it using the `const` keyword, then it's going to always be whatever value you initialize it to, in this case, ""

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `m_sEnviron` **isn't** a variable (/field) - it is a `const`; it is **always** `""`.

If it was a static property (or field), then `Programs.m_sEnviron`. If it was an instance property (or field) then `someInstance.m_sEnviron` should work, since it is `public` - but I would rename it.

I *expect* you mean it to be a `static` field; which *can* work, but you should at least be a little cautious that this doesn't necessarily play nicely if you start using multiple threads, etc. And public fields are generally best avoided (prefer private fields and public properties).

For example:

```
public static string Environ {get;set;}
```

would be a public, static property easily accessible as `Program.Environ`.

Comment: Hi Marc-  Based on what I placed below my question above, why am I still not seeing m_sEnviron in intellisense after I type Program. in my Logs class?  My syntax must be wrong huh?

Comment: Is it in the same project? Even in the same file, the way you've illustrated?

Comment: Yes that is all in the same file

Comment: @Josh - that should work, but you can only check the value *inside a method*.

Answer (score 1):

`const` basically makes the variable `static` and readonly. So `public const string m_sEnviron = "";` means that m_sEnviron will **ALWAYS** be the empty string. If you try and change it, you will get an error.

However, to access it from a method in the `Logs` class, you just access it just like a static variable:

```
string foo = Programs.m_sEnviron;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could specify the class where the variable is located as a static class which would therefore not require instantiation.

Comment: As the other answers mention, there is an issue here with you declaring the variable as a constant and then trying to change it.  The idea of a 'const' is that its value remains the same throughout the execution of the programme.  If you change it to a public variable:

public string myStr = Programs.m_sEnviron;

it can be accessed from other classes, however you must create an instance of the class in order to access the variable.  If you create the class as a static class you will be able to access the value of the variable publically from other classes without instantiating first