# How do you access data in another class in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to share data between classes in C#.  Sounds easy enough.  I have a collection that is loaded with data in a class.  Let's say it is defined like this:

```
public class AppAdmin: IApplicationThingy
{
     public ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection;
```

Now, in another class, I want to look at DataCollection.  Both classes are in the same namespace.  `AppAdmin.DataCollection` does not work.  Can you help?

Comment: Are you trying to access `AppAdmin` by `AppAdmin.DataCollection`? If that's the case it won't work simply because you can't access non-static members of a class, you'll have to access it via an _instance_ of `AppAdmin`.

Comment: Yeah, object oriented programming is slightly harder to understand than procedural programming. But you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking variable from a different class in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917096/checking-variable-from-a-different-class-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to have an instance of AppAdmin to access DataCollection

```
var appAdmin = new AppAdmin();
var data = addAdmin.DataCollection;
```

or if the design permits, you can make DataCollection static

```
public class AppAdmin: IApplicationThingy
{
     public static ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection;
```

and then you can access DataCollection as you mention in the question by

```
var data = AppAdmin.DataCollection;
```

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of it, you are trying to access an instance member like a static member.  Static members are attached to the class/type and and instance member is attached to an object.  If you are looking to access the "DataCollection"  as you have it above, you will need to create an AppAdmin object first and then you should be able to access it.

Try this.

```
var aAdmin = new AppAdmin();
var collection = aAdmin.DataCollection;
```

Answer (score 2):

`AppAdmin.DataCollection` is an instance member of `AppAdmin`. This means that you need an instance of `AppAdmin` to access `AppAdmin.DataCollection` for a particular instance.

Thus, at some point you need a reference (be it through a variable of type `AppAdmin` or an expression that evaluates to an instance of `AppAdmin`) to be able to access `AppAdmin.DataCollection` for a particular instance.

So, somehow, someway, you need

```
AppAdmin appAdmin = // expression that evaluates to an instance of AppAdmin
var dataCollection = appAdmin.DataCollection;
```

or

```
var dataCollection = 
   (expression that evaluates to an instance of AppAdmin).DataCollection
```

to get a reference to `AppAdmin.DataCollection` for a particular instance of `AppAdmin`.

Let's put it more simply:

```
class Dog {
    public IEnumerable<DogLeg> Legs { get; set; }
}
```

A `Dog` has `Legs`. To be able to get a particular `Dog`'s `Legs`, you need an instance of `Dog` to receive the request for its `Legs`.

Similarly, an `AppAdmin` has a `DataCollection`. You need a particular instance of `AppAdmin` to receive the request for its `DataCollection`.

So, to access an instance member (be it a field, property or method) you need an instance object to receive the request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the object and then call the data filed.

```
AppAdmin aa = new AppAdmin();

aa.DataCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an *instance* of the class in order to access its members.

In order to share the data in the instance, you need to pass it around:

```
// in one object that needs the object
var myAppAdmin = new AppAdmin():
var myData = myAppAdmin.DataCollection;

// call to another object, passing in the class
myOtherClass.GetDataFromAppAdmin(myAppAdmin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to make it static?

```
public class AppAdmin: IApplicationThingy
{
     static public ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends...

If the data just needs to always be available outside of any given instance of the object, just make it `static`:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection;
```

If the data is tied to an instance of the object, then you access it from the instance and not from the class:

```
var myObj = new AppAdmin();
myObj.DataCollection ...
```

But keep in mind the difference between *static* and *instance* values.  It's an important subject to learn.  Trying to mix the two often leads to strange bugs.